# Rails - what's the correct path for inner controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, controller, routes

I have this setup in the **routes.rb**:

```
resources :users do
  resources :images do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

When I load the **show** action from the **ImagesController**, this is what is in the template file:

```
...
= render 'comments/form', :@comment => @image.comments.new
...
```

and in the **comments/form** file is following:

```
= form_for [@comment.commentable, @comment] do |f|
  .field
    = f.text_field :body
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Comment'
```

And the **show** action:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @image = @user.images.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @image }
    end
  end
```

But when I load this page in the browser, I get this error:

```
undefined method `image_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007feb48488128>:0x007feb48399668>
```

Why Rails returns this error message?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type `rake routes` to see the right routes available in your app

Answer (score 0):

In your show method,

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @image = @user.images.find(params[:id])

  ## Add this line:
  @comment = @image.comments.build 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @image }
  end
end
```

In your template, if you are rendering a template,

```
= render "comments/form", :locals => { :comment => @comment } %>
```

In your `comments/form` write like this:

```
= form_for comment do |f|
 .field
   = f.text_field :body
 .actions
   = f.submit 'Comment'
```

It should work. Thanks